# How to align div to right using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I have a layout_cshtml, now my challenge is the aligning on my div its on the left and not showing well both search and dropdownlist. I need some help below to the logic its not aligning well yet its not good for the user experience including my nav is not showing at all to the Interface no errors at all, please help me based on what i have attempted.

```
//View
<nav>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("People")">People</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Modules")">Modules</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Files")"></a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Files")">Files</a></li>
                    
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>



    <center>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <li class="static ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tab-0" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true">
                <a href="#tab-0" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1">Everyone</a>
            </li>
            <form class="form-group ml-3">
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                    <input class="form-control form-control-navbar" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-navbar" type="submit">
                            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <!--DropdownlistFor-->
            @Html.DropDownList("eNtsaRegLists", new SelectList(ViewBag.eNtsaRegListsEnum, "Value", "Text"))
        </div>
    </center>
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example. Which `div` do you want to align? And what does this have to do with c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not sure what `<div>` you wanted to move, and I did not understand the point with adding `<nav>` when you dont have a `div` there.

Anyway here is an example on how you can do it.
I have used the float-class in bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/)

```
  <div class="form-group row float-right">
    <li class="static ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tab-0" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true">
      <a href="#tab-0" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1">Everyone</a>
    </li>
    <form class="form-group ml-3">
      <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
        <input class="form-control form-control-navbar" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-navbar" type="submit">
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>
```

[Codepen: https://codepen.io/cbrown___/pen/yLOqNym](https://codepen.io/cbrown___/pen/yLOqNym)

By the way you should make the codepen, not we who you want help from.

EDIT: Removed `<center>`

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't use the `<center>` tag anymore. It has been depreciated over 10 years ago. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp

Comment: Good point! Just copied the code from author. I removed it now.

Comment: You're welcome. In fact, my comment was also mainly directed towards the questioner.  I have already seen above that this all looks a bit "rustic".

Comment: @Andres thanks mate, yes i will refrain myself  for using center.

Comment: @BraGcobs : Remember to mark questions as answered. I see on your profile you have many questions that is not "answered" even though they have an answer (I dont know if they are correct or not)

Comment: @GerryMM881 i did accept this answer, some have not been answered based on what need